# add-in in VSTO - How to get text from Word document using Ribbon with button

Tags: c#, vsto

How can I do something with text in my word document using button in word add-in? I don't know, how to get text from document after click on the button, because Application is not accessible in Ribbon class.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using and which version of .Net?

Comment: Cant you able to access Globals.ThisAddin.Application in your Ribbon class

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following code should take the text found in the selection:

```
string textFromDoc;
textFromDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Text;
```

You can also specify the `Range` by:

```
textFromDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 20).Text;
```

This will take the first 20 letters written in the active document.
Bottom line, you can access Application by using:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
```